# Does a modified item found in the Items as Resources (IAR) file replace all fields in the database?

Tags: serialization, scs, items-as-resources

Assume an item is deployed to an environment for the first time contained within the IAR file.

- If a single field is modified does the entire item get replaced by data stored in the database?
- If a new version of the item is deployed in an updated IAR file, how does one determine whether or not to delete the database version?

### Update

I did a trivial test using the item `/sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules/Forms/FileStorageCleanup`.

A default installation of Sitecore XM 10.3 includes databases records for it even though it's in the IAR file. I first deleted the item which Sitecore reported that the item exists as a resource.

[image: Exists as a resource]

Then I saved the item with a new date in the **Last Run** field. Comparing with the database I now see rows for each of the fields.

```
USE [Sitecore.Master]
GO

DECLARE @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @ID = '{3D8F6795-1C4E-462D-8A81-BE27B1AEC5BD}'

SELECT *
FROM 
    [dbo].[Items] i
WHERE 
    i.ID = @ID

SELECT *
FROM 
    [dbo].[SharedFields] s
WHERE 
    s.ItemId = @ID

SELECT *
FROM 
    [dbo].[VersionedFields] v
WHERE 
    v.ItemId = @ID

SELECT *
FROM 
    [dbo].[UnversionedFields] u
WHERE 
    u.ItemId = @ID
```

[image: Database Records]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you modify the resource file items, a copy of the item (delta) will be stored in the database. Even though it is called `delta`, it contains values for all fields and not just the updated field. The next time the item is needed, it will be retrieved from the database instead of the resource file.

During the upgrade process, in `Section 3.1.3` Clean up the content databases, you will be instructed to use the `Sitecore UpdateApp tool` to remove the obsolete items from the databases. The `Sitecore UpdateApp tool` will find the item based on the resource files that you have provided to the folder and remove any items that do not have any changes.

For e.g. let us assume you updated one of the OOB `SXA` scripts in Sitecore which are present as `IAR` by adding a rule on them. Since you have modified a field of the script, it will not be removed. Once the upgrade process is done, you will reinstall the latest version of `SXA` to the new upgraded instance. The modified script in the database will still take precedence and be loaded instead of the newer version that comes from a resource file.

In short, modifying the script will not affect the upgrade process. Your changes on the script will remain.